KITTI IMU data gaps interpolation
I am using some IMU data from KITTI raw dataset. There are gaps in OxTs IMU data. I want to interpolate the gaps. The data looks periodically. Is there any way to interpolate them realistically? Below is the visualization of accelerations at XYZ axis.



I tried to fit the data with a trigonometric function, however it was not good enough.
def trigonometric_model2(t, a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, a4, b4, a5, b5, a6, b6, a7, b7, a8, b8, c):
    return (a1 * np.sin(b1 * t) + a2 * np.cos(b2 * t) + 
            a3 * np.sin(b3 * t) + a4 * np.cos(b4 * t) + 
            a5 * np.sin(b5 * t) + a6 * np.cos(b6 * t) + 
            a7 * np.sin(b7 * t) + a8 * np.cos(b8 * t) + 
            c)
# data is a n * 4 array. 
# The first col is the timestamps,
# The second col is the acceleration at x direction
# The third col is the accelration at the y direction
# The last col is the acceleration at the z direction 
ts = data[:, 0] # there is an ~2 second gap as shown above 
axs = data[:, 1]

# try to fit the model on the data
params, _ = curve_fit(trigonometric_model2, ts, axs, maxfev=60000)

# predict the data for the gap
xs = np.linspace(ts[0], ts[-1], 500)
ys = trigonometric_model2(xs, *params)


Here is the sample data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSjnnPQR-p2iB-EYGVJw6XLkzfMQ5XNz6dmj8WaJElM/edit?usp=sharing

Several things to improve here:

be sure to scale your data before passing into the model. For example divide your time axis by mean value xs / np.max(xs)
Increase number of sin/cos parameters. Ideally you can tune parameter N - which influence number of sin/cos that you will use.
convergence can be improved if you'll provide good initiall guess for the parameters

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def trig_model(t, *args):
    """
        args have 2*N + 1 coefficients:
        - constant
        - 2*N coefficients for sin/cos
    """
    c, args = args[0], args[1:]
    n = len(args) // 2 

    res = c
    for i in range(n):
        # smallest period is when i=0 and is equal to T = 2 
        # so the data `t` should either be inside interval [0,2]
        # or have period less less or equal 2.

        res += args[2*i] * np.sin(np.pi * t * (1+i)) + \
               args[2*i+1] * np.cos(np.pi * t *(1+i))

    
    return res


xs = df['t']
ys = df['ax']

# intial guess of the parameters
n = 8
params0 = np.random.random(2*n+1) 
params0[0] = np.mean(ys) # constant

# scalling the data
xs = xs / np.max(xs)

params, _ = curve_fit(trig_model, xs,ys, p0 = params0)
y_pred = trig_model(xs, *params)

params

Result with n=8

Result with n=20


Hi, thank you for your help! I have two questions: 1. What are the xs and ys in your code? 2.  Where is the gap in the time? Did you just ignore them?

ah, sorry, I hadn't seen the shared data, so reused my own. XS and YS are the same as X and Y

The main problem is that I want to predict the missing data in the gap.

My original code was too unclear, I updated it

I have updated my answer given the data shared.

About the predictions - unfortunately there is no guarantee that the method that you've chosen for interpolation will give good results. You need to try different approaches and select the one that will give you best results

Yes I just tried your code. It did fit the existing data much better. However, for the predicted values in the gap, it is still very bad.
